# multiple async calls using rxjava

Tags: java, asynchronous, parallel-processing

How to achieve multiple async calls with Rxjava, where each call gets responses in chunks.

Suppose when a user initiates a request, I need to fetch various data from a set of async services.
User Requests data -> I need to make calls to Service A, Service B and Service C in an async manner.

Each of these services is defined in a way that for a given request A -> they will respond data in chunks say A1, A2, A3, and AF. Similarly, service B will response B1, B2, BF and Service C will respond in chunks C1, C2, C3, C4, CF.
Where numerics represent the chunks and F represents the final response. The response has flag final if they have sent data for the all requested information.

For one given request from the user, I make calls to A, B, C (can be in sequence or parallel), I would like to process all the responses from these services and know when I got data back from all the three. For me, I need to know the complete status that is when data from all the services is processed.

Also how to dispose the subscriber

```
public void processUserRequest(){
    Observable.fromIterable(listofservices)
              .flatMap (service -> invokeAsyncService(service))
              .subscribe( resp -> process response, error -> process 
    error , () -> done);
}  //end processUserRequest


public Observable invokeAsyncService(){
   PublishSubject subject = PublishSubject.create();
   callService(request, subject);  // internally in callService subject's      onNext and onComplete are used for emitting responses from the service call. 
   return subject;
} //end invokeAsyncService
```

Comment: I created a parent observable, which is an observable of multiple PublishSubject for each service call. The PublishSubject's onNext and onComplete are used to publishing the events for chunks and final responses from services.

I have one subscriber to the root observable. Everything seems to work fine, but not sure if it the right way of doing.

Comment: Observable.fromIterable(listofservices)
                  .flatMap (service -> invokeAsyncService(service))
                  .subscribe( resp -> process response, error -> process error , () -> done);

public Observable invokeAsyncService(){
       PublishSubject subject = PublishSubject.create();
       callService(request, subject);  // internally in callService i used onNext and onComplete on subject passed for emitting responses from the service call. 
       return subject;
}